# Adding remaing value into another field

Tags: mysql, sql

tbl_Emi

```
CardNo                   EMI        DTE            REC      DTE          STS 
5140560000001142        934.00  2014-03-28     500.00    2014-05-22      P 
5140560000001142        934.00  2014-04-30       0.00    2014-05-22      P
```

---

tbl_Fin

```
CardNo                   EMI        DTE            REC      DTE          STS 
5140560000001142        934.00  2014-04-30     500.00    2014-05-22      P
```

I have 2 tables:

- tbl_Emi: Final Results table
- tbl_Fin: A table that has updated records through time intervals.

Each table has the following columns:

```
CardNo (id)
EMI (amount owing)
DTE (payment deadline date)
REC (received amount)
DTE (payment receival date)
```

Please let me know if adding more data record will be useful.

Comment: It looks like your emi is a column not a record.

Comment: use `case` - check if `rec + 500 > emi`, if not just update, if yes update and insert

Comment: That is correct, but how can I add the remaining amount to the other record

Comment: Could you please add more sample data so we can test it better, if it always has the correct result? And add the desired result (also to make your question more clear). And your column `DTE` is not unique.

Comment: I would like to:

 1. Read records from tbl_Fin
 2. Match them to CardNo records from tbl_Eim